# Converting From an Applet to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, awt

I made a shooting game where slimes randomly appear and you have to shoot at them.  However it was made using an `Applet`, and I'm having trouble embedding it into a webpage. So I resorted to trying to turn it into a `JFrame`.  Besides adding the main method and extending `JFrame` instead of `Applet`, what else should I do?

```
package ss;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import sun.audio.*;
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Slimeshooter extends Applet implements Runnable, MouseListener{
        AudioStream stream = null;      
        AudioStream stream2 = null;
        public Graphics d;
        public BufferedImage redS, blueS, orangeS, greenS, purpleS, yellowS, chosenSlime, goat;
        public Image offscreen;
        public boolean slimeSpawn;
        public boolean changeSlime;
        public int posX;
        public int posY;
        public int hits, misses;
        public static int secondsleft = 60;
        public static Thread th2;
        public boolean finished = false;


        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")



        public void run(){

            String bgmusic = "bgmusic.wav";
            InputStream in2 = null;
            try {
                in2 = new FileInputStream(bgmusic);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                stream2 = new AudioStream(in2);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
            AudioPlayer.player.start(stream2);

            slimeSpawn = true;
            try {
                blueS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimeBlue.png"));
                redS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimeRed.png"));
                yellowS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimeYellow.png"));
                orangeS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimeOrange.png"));
                purpleS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimePurple.png"));
                greenS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimeGreen.png"));
                goat = ImageIO.read(new File("goat.png"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while(true){
                  if(secondsleft > 0){
                      th2 = new Thread();
                      try {
                          th2.sleep(1000);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e){
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }

                      secondsleft--;
                  } else {
                      finished = true;
                      repaint();
                  }





                 if(slimeSpawn == true){
                     posX = (int) (Math.random() * 1860);
                     posY = (int) (Math.random() * 958);
                    int slimeColor = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
                      if(slimeColor == 0){
                          chosenSlime = blueS;
                          slimeSpawn = false;
                          repaint();
                      }
                      if(slimeColor == 1){
                          chosenSlime = yellowS;
                          slimeSpawn = false;
                          repaint();
                      }
                      if(slimeColor == 2){
                          chosenSlime = purpleS;
                          slimeSpawn = false;;
                          repaint();
                      }
                      if(slimeColor == 3){
                          chosenSlime = greenS;
                          slimeSpawn = false;
                          repaint();
                      }
                      if(slimeColor == 4){
                          chosenSlime = orangeS;
                          slimeSpawn = false;
                          repaint();
                      }
                      if(slimeColor == 5){
                          chosenSlime = redS;
                          slimeSpawn = false;
                          repaint();
                      }


             }


            }



            }
        public void spawnSlime(){

        if(changeSlime == true){
            repaint();
            posX = (int) (Math.random() * 1860);
            posY = (int) (Math.random() * 958);
        int slimeColor = (int) (Math.random() * 6);
          if(slimeColor == 0){
              chosenSlime = blueS;
              slimeSpawn = false;
              repaint();
          }
          if(slimeColor == 1){
              chosenSlime = yellowS;
              slimeSpawn = false;
              repaint();
          }
          if(slimeColor == 2){
              chosenSlime = purpleS;
              slimeSpawn = false;;
              repaint();
          }
          if(slimeColor == 3){
              chosenSlime = greenS;
              slimeSpawn = false;
              repaint();
          }
          if(slimeColor == 4){
              chosenSlime = orangeS;
              slimeSpawn = false;
              repaint();
          }
          if(slimeColor == 5){
              chosenSlime = redS;
              slimeSpawn = false;
              repaint();

          }
        }
        changeSlime = false;
              repaint();
        }

        public void init(){
            setSize(2000,2000);
            Thread th = new Thread(this);
            th.start();
            addMouseListener(this);
            offscreen = createImage(2000,2000);
            d = offscreen.getGraphics();
        }
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            spawnSlime();
            d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            d.fillRect(0, 0, 2000, 2500);
            d.drawImage(chosenSlime, posX, posY, this);
            g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this); 
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 40));
            g.drawString("Hits: " + Integer.toString(hits), 10, 40);
            g.drawString("Misses: " + Integer.toString(misses), 10, 80);
            g.drawString("Time Left: " + Integer.toString(secondsleft), 10, 120);
            if(finished == true){
                int divide = hits/misses;
                String divided = Integer.toString(divide);
                g.drawString("You finished with the hit miss ratio of ABOUT... " + divided, 10, 160);
            }
         }




        public void update(Graphics g){
             paint(g);  
        }
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {


            String gunsound = "gun.wav";
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(gunsound);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                stream = new AudioStream(in);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
            AudioPlayer.player.start(stream);

            // Test if the player clicked the slime
            if((e.getX() < posX + 50 && e.getY() < posY + 50) && (e.getX() > posX && e.getY()  > posY)){
                changeSlime = true;
                hits++;
            }
            else {
                misses++;
            }





        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

    }
```

Comment: *"Besides adding the main method and extending JFrame instead of Applet, what else should I do?"* - Not that. Use a `JPanel` as your base class, then it doesn't matter which container you add it to. The added bonus is, Swing components are double buffered by default, so you don't need you double buffering code

Comment: I'd also have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) as you need to be concious of the threading issues and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible solution to rolling your own thread

Comment: `blueS = ImageIO.read(new File("slimeBlue.png"));` Did that ever work as an applet?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson yeah the png was in the src folder and it showed up in the applet.

Comment: MadProgrammer so by using as a base class, do you mean use "extends JFrame" instead of Applet right? Then in my init() add a JPanel and set it's size and all, and then in my main method create a JFrame and add the JPanel?